# Google Maps API V3 change Marker Option

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: image,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    flat: true,
    optimized: false,
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    customInfo: locations[i][0]
    });
```

I have the above to build my Marker in my Google Map but when the marker is clicked, the map zooms to the location and I'd like to make the marker non clickable.

I have tried the following with no success

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(17);
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    marker.MarkerOptions ({
        clickable: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it and its actually quite a simple way of doing it.

```
marker.setClickable (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) - the name of the method you are looking for is called `setOptions`

```
marker.setOptions({clickable:false});
```