# Google Map API - how to change default cursor on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know how to change default cursor when user move it on marker or map.circle. 
On google developers page I found how to change draggableCursor or draggingCursor but there is nothing about clickable cursor.

Default on marker, cursor change to "cursor: pointer", I would like to keep cursor as a "openhand" and keep marker "clickable".

Thank you

Comment: @scaisEdge You can set a marker's `clickable` property to false: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions

Comment: @duncan you are right..

Comment: And then I cant click. Marker must be clickable, so I can't set this property to "false".

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953539/google-maps-api-v3-change-marker-option or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884401/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-non-clickable. It might help you.

Comment: No, it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API explicitly provides a function to set the cursor:

```
marker.setCursor('default');
```

Edit: This does not provide the *openhand* cursor, which is actually an [image](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/openhand.c%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bur). I couldn't find anything to use a custom image as a cursor for a marker.

But if you provide a random value to the `setCursor` function, the cursor reverts back to the default *openhand* image.

```
marker.setCursor('xyz');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine for the marker but It doesn't work for a map.circle object. Do you know how to set it for circle?

Comment: Nothing works! And there is no reference at all in the documentation. Nowhere it says that a random image can be used as cursor for a marker (though it's possible for the whole map). And probably `setCursor(xyz)` is a bug!